# Alternate implementation of TCL's keyed list which does not have to be compiled?

Tags: tcl, associative-array

I need to use keyed lists with TCL, but have the option of only copying tcl code to the device.

The default method is to use [TclX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tclx/), but this requires compilation.

Is there any implementation of keyed list functions (keylset, keylget) which is available as a "standalone" library (i.e. pure tcl)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at  [this wiki page regarding keyed lists](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2519), where someone has written a pure tcl version of basic keyed list functionality. I didn't read in depth to see if they depended on dict or not. If so, there is a pure tcl implemention of dict elsewhere on the wiki.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out 15 minutes after posting here :) Anyway I needed a 8.3 compliant version, which it was not, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

yes, in tcl 8.5, the `dict` command was added which implements a dictionary store, for example:

```
dict set d key1 val1
dict set d key2 val2

dict for {k v} $d {puts "$k = $v"}
```

Comment: I am looking for something compatible with 8.3 . Sorry for not specifying this in the Question. Have found the solution.

Comment: If you have the time, it might be worth taking the pure Tcl keyed list implementation and re-implementing it using dicts instead raw lists. The reason being that the dict code is (I believe) optimized for the type of access you need and would likely be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution at the end of [this wiki page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2519) itself !